# Where do custom folders of virtual users with dovecot IMAP get stored?

Tags: dovecot, maildir

I just set up a Postfix+Dovecot Mail System. This system uses only virtual users. I set the mailboxes up in `/var/vmail/DOMAIN/USER` in the `Maildir` format. Now I connected (successfully :D) with my IMAP Client to the thing and created a folder and moved an existing mail from INBOX to the folder. And now I can't find this mail on the file-system. It is gone from `cur` but there is no other folder created in `/var/vmail/DOMAIN/USER`.

Where do the folders go?

Comment: How did you move the existing mail, if it was in another location previously? I would expect that you can only access `/var/vmail/DOMAIN/USER` via IMAP. Where is this `cur` you mention located in the file system? Did you perhaps move it to a local folder on your client? You do know that subfolders start with a dot in Maildir format (so you need `ls -a` option)?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that. Now I found the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not use the `-a` option to `ls`, to show files starting with a dot (sometimes called hidden files because of this).

Maildir format dictates that sub-folder directories start with a dot, so when you see "Trash" in your list of folders in your IMAP client, the files are stored in a directory called `.Trash`, etc. These directories again contain the usual Maildir trio of `new`, `cur` and `tmp`.